# How do I nest resource identifiers?

Tags: .net, msdn, resx

The page [Names of Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229037(v=vs.100)) on MSDN says the following.

> **Do use the dot separator (".") to nest identifiers with a clear hierarchy.**
>
> For example, names such as `Menus.FileMenu.Close.Text` and `Menus.FileMenu.Close.Color` conform to this guideline.

How do I do this? When I try to, I'm told a dot is not valid in a resource identifier, like this.

[image: Disappointing.]

I can understand why it's not valid<sup>[1]</sup>, which is why I always assumed it wasn't possible to nest resource identifiers, and never tried until now... but MSDN says I can. What am I missing?

[1] From looking at the auto-generated `Resource.Designer.cs` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this too and it looks like it has been around for a few years now.

The strong type generator generates a strong typed class, and maps each resource to a property of that class. The resource name (identifier) will be used as the name of the property. An identifier with a dot character is not valid in C# (as you declared in the question). However, the generator will replace the dot with underscore so you still get a valid strong typed class.

I usually just replace the dot with an underscore. It's strange though that they still haven't changed that in the guidelines. (Or maybe I have missed something?)

Comment: Also did the same with underscore character.

Comment: I've noticed from reflection that internally Microsoft seems to use underscores to separate resources, so maybe it *is* just out-of-date documentation.

Comment: "However, the generator will replace the dot with underscore" I've not been able to get that to happen. It just complains like in my screenshot.

Comment: @apkd You mean in the resource editor? Because in the generated class the property has underscores instead of dots. Though the property will still use a string with dots to fetch the resource.

Comment: How are you adding the resource? I can't add one with dots http://i.imgur.com/9874h.png

Comment: @apkd I'm adding it the same way you do, in the resource editor. I also get the same warning, but if I choose to ignore it and go where I want to use the resource (let's say the .resx-file is named *Resource1.resx* and the generated class is `Resource1`) and call my property it would look like: `var s = Resource1.This_Is_A_Test;` but the identifier in the resource editor would still be *This.Is.A.Test*. Maybe we are misunderstanding each other =)

Comment: oh! That'll teach me to listen to VS. I just assumed it wouldn't accept it, and I didn't actually try ignoring the error and using it anyway. I see now. I'll just stick to what I've been doing and use underscores in the resource editor, then.